# How to run Execute Left Trajectory and Execute Right Trajectory services?

Tags: ros, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed tutorials [Warehouse Viewer](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/tools/Warehouse%20Viewer)

I run these command successfully,and it also show 2 pr2 on 2 rviz window.

```
  roslaunch pr2_test_arm_navigation planning_components_visualizer.launch
  roscd move_arm_warehouse;
  ./scripts/create_launch_files.py pr2_test
  roslaunch pr2_test_arm_navigation planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_pr2_test.launch
```

But when I click accept button,it shows ROS Arm Navigation Warehouse Viewer logo,but couldn't get in.

[image: image description]

I also find that webpage says

```
  Warning: Do not check "Use Robot Data" while the Execute Left Trajectory and Execute Right Trajectory services are not being advertised. Make sure they are running by invoking rosservice. Otherwise, the viewer will hang on startup while waiting for these (or any other) services.
```

How to run Execute Left Trajectory and Execute Right Trajectory services?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11621/how-to-run-execute-left-trajectory-and-execute-right-trajectory-services?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed (after several trials) to get the warehouse running on the PR2. You can check a previous answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2445/arm-navigation-warehouse-on-the-pr2).

There you will find a more detailed PDF tutorial. If you still have problems I can try to put the right configuration files somewhere.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0